# How is 1,4,6-trichlorodiamantane optically inactive?

Tags: isomers, optical-properties

[image]

How this compound is optically inactive I can't analyse any element of symmetry in this compound.

Comment: The picture quality is low, but maybe one of the C-C bonds is drawn incorrectly, too.  Did you build a molecular model with a model kit?  Try, and give the flow scheme next to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_symmetry#Point_groups_and_permutation-inversion_groups a chance.

Comment: Where did you invent such a monstrosity?

Comment: It could be an adamantane derivative. I may be mistaken, but it should then have 3 mirror planes. I strongly advise building a model, either in a computer or with a kit.

Comment: The sketch is wrong. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamantan

Comment: In a correct sketch of this molecule, you immediately see that all chloride atoms lie in the mirror plane that is spanned by the two CC bonds that are furthest apart.

Comment: Just out of curiousity, where does that picture come from?

Comment: @Karl tis' certainly a JEE practice questionXD

Comment: @HappyFeetMe _Potentially_ inspired on claim #4 of this patent, and the NMR spectra included https://patents.google.com/patent/EP1760057A1/en

Comment: M. C. Escher would have been proud of this picture.

Comment: Yes I am pretty sure this is a question from one of the many question banks available for the Indian competitive exam, the JEE. Unfortunately, in my experience, the authors for such books more often than not make erroneous questions in their attempt to make them complicated

Answer (score 8):

From this indeed Escheresque' screen photo,  I *assume* the following molecular structure:

[image]

which reveals to be and example of

> point group $C_s$ or a *meso*-compound

---

*Note:*  There is a nice interactive symmetry gallery at [Otterbein.edu](https://symotter.org/), accessible by a web browser.